# How to allow default value when using binding for custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, styles

All, I am working on a custom control of ours that has a `Border` with a `Background` set to the below

```
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFF7F7F7" Offset="0.164" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDBDBDB" Offset="0.664" />
    <GradientStop Color="#FFB3B3B3" Offset="0.978" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

However, I want to allow the user to override this. I created a dependency property of type `Brush`, however I cannot figure out how to bind to the Background, while still having this default in the XAML. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [TemplateBinding Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type your:YourControl}">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF7F7F7" Offset="0.164" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FFDBDBDB" Offset="0.664" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FFB3B3B3" Offset="0.978" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Then in some part of your default ControlTemplate:

```
<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
  ....
</Border>
```

This will allow the consumer to override the default Background, while maintaining the Style-defined one:

```
<your:YourControl/> <!-- Will use default Background -->

<your:YourControl Background="Green"/> <!-- will have Green background -->
```

Comment: Just to clarify for anybody in the future. `Background` must remain null for rounding and other aesthetics, so I had to create a `WindowBackground` dependency property. However, `Background` can be replaced by any dependency property of the control, even custom ones :)